# Python : How to assign new value from outside of the function but the value is inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why val can't access inside bar after declare new val's value inside bar?

```
def foo() -> None:
        val = 'not change yet'
        def bar() -> None:
            print(val)        # Error: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment
            val = 'changed'
            print(val)
        bar()
foo()
```

How can I overcome the issue?
PS: I don't want to put val outside foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `val` as `nonlocal`.

```
def foo() -> None:
        val = 'not change yet'
        def bar() -> None:
            nonlocal val
            print(val)        # Error: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment
            val = 'changed'
            print(val)
        bar()
foo()
```

Take a look here: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_nonlocal.asp)